# Do I need a captcha for my contact form (to stop spam) if the message is only sent when a user token is validated?

Tags: javascript, php, jwt, captcha, spam-prevention

I am building an app for a company with javascript, html and php.(packaged up with phonegap)

The app is only for paying subscribers of the company and the user will only gain access to the app after login details
are validated.

Once login details are validated (on the server side), a JWT token is generated with the user's ID (using the [JWT.class.php](https://github.com/rmcdaniel/angular-codeigniter-seed/blob/master/api/application/helpers/jwt_helper.php))

```
include_once '../includes/JWT.class.php';
$token = array();
$token['userID'] = $loginDetails['userID'];
$data['usertoken'] = JWT::encode($token, 'secret_server_key');
```

This token is then sent back to client side and stored in local storage.

On every subsequent http request (with ajax) the token is sent to the server side and validated before any 
processes are carried out.

I was about to add a captcha to a contact form I have in the app, however now I am wondering if it is necessary?

When the form is submitted all fields are validated first.
If fields are valid then they are sent to story_form_handler.php.

Here is my javascript function called when the form is submitted.

```
function submitContactForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var story_subject = $('#contact_input3').val();  
    var story_message = $('#contact_input4').val();  
    var contact_email_address = $("#contact_input1").val();
    var contact_full_name = $("#contact_input0").val();
    var contact_phone = $("#contact_input2").val();

    var subjectIsValid = validateInput(story_subject, subjectRegex);
    var messageIsValid = validateInput(story_message, messageRegex);
    var emailIsValid = validateInput(contact_email_address, emailRegex);
    var fullNameIsValid = validateInput(contact_full_name, displayNameRegex);
    var phoneNumberIsValid = validateInput(contact_phone, phoneNumberRegex);


    if((story_subject == "" || story_subject == null) || 
        (story_message == "" || story_message == null) || 
        (contact_email_address == "" || ccontact_email_address == null) ||
        (contact_full_name == "" || contact_full_name == null)){

        //display error

    }else if((!subjectIsValid) || (!emailIsValid) || (!phoneNumberIsValid) || (!messageIsValid) || (!fullNameIsValid)){
            if(!subjectIsValid){
                //display error
            }else if(!phoneNumberIsValid){
                //display error
            }else if(!emailIsValid){
                //display error
            }else if(!fullNameIsValid){
                //display error
            }else if(!messageIsValid){
                //display error
            }
    }else{

        var token = localStorage.getItem("usertoken");  
        var params = {'usertoken': token, 'story_subject': story_subject, 'story_message':story_message, 'contact_full_name':contact_full_name, 'contact_email_address':contact_email_address, 'contact_phone':contact_phone};                                      

            $.ajax({    
                url: app_root_url + 'story_form_handler.php',
                data: JSON.stringify(params), 
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                var result = data;
                var token_is_valid = result.token_is_valid;

                console.log("token_is_valid" + token_is_valid); 

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                //error

            }
        });
    }

}
```

story_form_handler.php

```
include_once '../includes/JWT.class.php';

$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($rawPostData);

if(isset($json->usertoken)){
    try{
    $token = JWT::decode($json->usertoken, 'secret_server_key'); //this will return an error if token has been tampered with    

        $data = array();

        if($token->userID){
            //token is valid and therefore user is valid so we go ahead submit the form.
            $data['token_is_valid'] = true;

            //send contact form

        }else{
            //token is set but is not valid
            $data['token_is_valid'] = false;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e) {

        $data['token_is_valid'] = false;
        echo json_encode($data);

    }   

}else{
    //token is not set. 
    $data['token_is_valid'] = false;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: How often do you imagine an average user would submit the form?

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic for SO. But if your users needs to be signed in, then that alone has eliminated the majority of it. *Personally* I just use recaptcha for users not signed in.

Comment: @mulquin an average user might submit the form 1-4 times a month. and there will be around 600-800 users (and more as time goes on).

Comment: @Qirel Can you tell me why its off-topic? ...Maybe it would have been better to post on code review?....  Anyway your answer helped thanks

Comment: Captha and authorization may look similar but have entirely different purpose .Since you said form is accessible only to authorized users , i think they would hardly ever spam contact forms and incase they did it's very easy to detect so i would say catha isn't needed here.

Comment: Because it's opinion-based :-) @Sarah

Comment: @Novice yes, these particular users definitely wont be interested in spamming.  thanks for your help.

Comment: @Qirel I see. I was looking for opinions from experienced developers and the answers have helped me a lot for this project :)